# Как разрешить элементу выходить за границу родителя

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать слайдер, но не знаю как сделать, чтобы элементы смогли выходить за границу свого родителя и там скрывались.
Код похож на тот, что у меня на сайте: 
суть в том, чтобы они не падали, а добавлялись дальше и скрывались

```js
{let worksArray = [];
 for(let i=0;i<7;i++){
     let newWork = {'img':i+1}
     worksArray.push(newWork);
 }
 for(let i=0;i<worksArray.length;i++){
     let whichBlock;
     if(i%2 != 0) whichBlock = '.top-sliders';
     else whichBlock = '.bottom-sliders';
     $(whichBlock).append('<div class="slider-item backgorund-image" style="background-image:url(css/images/works/'+worksArray[i].img+'.png")></div>');
 }
}
```

```css
#slider-wrapper{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}
.top-sliders{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 220px;
    background: blue;
}
.bottom-sliders{
    height: 280px;
    background: red;
}
.slider-item{
    background: grey;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50%;
}
.slider-item:hover{
    background-color: rgba(26,188,156, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="top-sliders"></div>
        <div class="bottom-sliders"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @soledar10 тогда уж и слайдам нужно display:inline-block

Comment: Размер слайдов фиксированный?

Comment: да, но может бить случайная ширина скриптом

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: ну в плане. размер слайдов картинок по висоте одинаков, а ширина может случайно задаваться там например от 200 до 500 пикселей скриптом(просто на макете разние размеры у картинок)

Comment: top-sliders и bottom-sliders ширина просто на всю страницу. в них уже добавляются слайды

Comment: Вы изображения ставите на фон слайдам. как от этого может меняться их ширина?

Comment: тут без этой функции с шириной

Comment: мне главное чтобы они не падали. я думал сделать им position:absolute я так делал уже. Но вроде они тогда налоажтся друг на друга

Comment: добавьте внутри слайдеров новый контейнер и установите ему ширину, равную сумме размером ваших изображений

Comment: тогда он выйдет за границу top-sliders например(если верхние слайды) и смогу прокручивать?